# Js foreach for creating table heads

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm using below code for creating table heading dynamically.

```
var tableHeaders = "<th>No</th>";
            tableHeaders += "<th>Devices</th>";
            tableHeaders += "<th>Users</th>";
    response.forEach(function(entry){ 
                            entry.chartElements.forEach(function(childrenEntry) {
                              tableHeaders += "<th>" + childrenEntry.label + "</th>";
                            });
                        });
```

Only the **tableHeaders** outside the foreach is working, It is not appending  tag inside the foreach. What i'm doing wrong here.!!!!

Server response

```
0: Object
      chartElements: [{count: 1
                     label: "Lollipop"
                     totalCount: 0}]
      deviceCount: 1
      deviceName: "Lenovo"

1: Object
    chartElements: [{count: 1
                     label: "Lollipop"
                     totalCount: 0}]
      deviceCount: 1
      deviceName: "Zenfone"
2: Object
    chartElements: [{count: 1
                     label: "Lollipop"
                     totalCount: 0}]
      deviceCount: 1
      deviceName: "MotoG"
3: Object
    chartElements: [{count: 1
                     label: "Lollipop"
                     totalCount: 0}]
      deviceCount: 1
      deviceName: "Nexus5
```

"

Comment: Is it actually entering the forEach? Did you verify that?

Comment: Yes it is entering the foreach.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Is `response` an array or just an object?

Comment: response is an array of objects and each object contains another array , which is chartElements.

Comment: and no errors in the console.

Comment: @boycod3 is it entering both forEach?

Comment: yes it is..i made same scenario inside jsfiddle and it is working great..What i'm doing wrong here

Comment: [simulating](https://jsfiddle.net/scottjustin5000/zkvqdgyk/) your code all works as expected.  Adding console.log to each forEach, what do you see logged?